# postgres LIKE % operator vs similarity - pg_trgm.similarity_threshold . different query plans

Tags: postgresql, indexing, similarity, query-planner

If I use:

```
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.9;
... where column % 'some string s';
```

PostgreSQL does an index scan on: gin (column gin_trgm_ops)

In contrast, which should be the same:

```
... where similarity(column, 'some string s' ) >= 0.9
```

That does a seqential scan instead of using the index.

From the documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgtrgm.html

> `text % text`  boolean
> Returns true if its arguments have a similarity that is greater than the current similarity threshold set by `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`.

Why?

Comment: IIRC postgres cannot apply indices on function calls but only on operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, a `WHERE` condition must look like this to allow an index scan:

```
<indexed expression> <operator> <constant>
```

Here, `<indexed expression>` is what you created the index on `<operator>` is an operator supported by the operator family of the index's operator class, and `<constant>` is an expression that is constant for the duration of the index scan (in particular, it can only contain `STABLE` functions).

The one exception in PostgreSQL is if you use a function returning `boolean` in the `WHERE` condition, and that function has an optimizer support function that allows PostgreSQL to substitute an index scan. But `similarity` is no such function.

Comment: What do you mean by "boolean function"?

Comment: @Bergi A function returning a `boolean`.

Comment: What would be examples of such functions - I can only find [boolean operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-logical.html)? When you say that it has "*an optimiser support function*", that implies it must be a builtin one?

Comment: `create index  on tenk1 (starts_with(stringu1,'abc'));
 explain (costs off) select * from tenk1 where starts_with(stringu1,'abc');` @Bergi  maybe something like this.

Comment: @jian Nah, that's an expression index, which works on any immutable function

Comment: https://git.postgresql.org/cgit/postgresql.git/tree/src/test/regress/expected/misc_functions.out#n554 maybe this one @Bergi

Comment: @jian Yeah, but is that actually used somewhere except tests? Is there a core function that does this, or is this mostly for extensions?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CACowWR3jZ4Xo1atU5xTDpEoeeKSw1%3D%3DsKPhCy3a29HtcE9oQVQ%40mail.gmail.com#991fe612929d7a7bc3dd53212077e638  it's a niche thing.
`where hundred =1111` is  same as `where int4eq(hundred,1111)` but second won't use  index scan  @Bergi

Comment: @Bergi Most of the index support for PostGIS works that way; queries like `... WHERE st_contains(...)`. [Here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/optimizer-support-functions/) is an article about the feature.